# Unique Top 5 Random Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting

Let's say I have an app that determine the winners in a prize drawing.  All entries are entered into a table indicating their employeeID.  Each employee can enter the drawing multiple times.  I select from the table, order by newid to get a random sort.  I assume the more entries (database records) an employee has the better chance he will end up in the top 5 of my query each time I run it.  So far so good.  However, because each employee has multiple records, there is a good chance he will come up multiple times in the top 5.  I need the ability to return 5 unique records from the randomly sorted results.

How do I get 5 unique rows while still ensuring those with multiple drawing entries get a heavier weighting in the selection?

My base query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 employeeID
 FROM events 
   TABLESAMPLE(1000 ROWS) 
 ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID());
```

Kinda what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
    FROM events 
    WHERE employeeID IN (SELECT employeeID
     FROM events 
       TABLESAMPLE(1000 ROWS) 
     ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
     )
 ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

But of course I cannot do an order by in the subquery.

Comment: `multiple drawing entries get a heavier weightin`  doesnt sound like a random selection does it?

Comment: If you look at it like employees putting ticket stubs into a drawing barrel.  For every ticket I put in, I get a chance to win.  The catch is, once I win one of the 5 prizes, I am not eligible to win any other prize.  You could look at it like, once my name is drawn, remove all my other tickets.

Comment: I suppose I could grab a top 1 employeeID, add it to a temp table and select again.  Only add the next selected employeeID if it does not already exist in the temp table.  But I suspect there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any solution must take into account 2 things:

- If an employee enter multiple tickets, his chance of winning increases relative to other.
- Everyone can only win once

Here's my approach:

```
;WITH
    tmp1 AS
    (
        SELECT      EmployeeID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS SortOrder
        FROM        Events
    ),
    tmp2 AS
    (
        SELECT      EmployeeID,
                    MIN(SortOrder) AS WinOrder
        FROM        tmp1
        GROUP BY    EmployeeID
    )


SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM tmp2
ORDER BY WinOrder
```

The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7714c/1/0) gives employees 1 & 5 higher chances to win, but they will only win once each, regardless of how many times they enter.

Comment: I was leaning towards this kind of solution.  So far it seems to work very well. Your description above states the problem quite well, couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple way to get what you're after:

```
select top 5 EmployeeID
from
(
    select EmployeeID, row_number() over (order by newid()) DrawOrder
    from Events
) wins
group by EmployeeID
order by min(DrawOrder)
```